# Unauthorization Error For swagger UI whille accessing it through azure function app URL

Tags: c#, azure, swagger

I am getting Unauthorized error while accessing swagger ui through azure function app url like this.

[image]

It is working fine while i am running in localhost but through azure url swagger ui is not even loading.

My code looks like this :-

Startup Class :-

```
    [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace ADPScheduleRequestService
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            //Register the extension
            builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), opts =>
            {
                opts.SpecVersion = OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0;
                opts.AddCodeParameter = true;
                opts.PrependOperationWithRoutePrefix = true;
                //opts.XmlPath = "TestFunction.xml";
                opts.Documents = new[]
                {
                    new SwaggerDocument
                    {
                        Name = "v1",
                        Title = "ADP Schedule Request Service",
                        Version = "v2",                       
                    }
                };
                opts.Title = "ADP";
                opts.ConfigureSwaggerGen = x =>
                {
                    //x.OperationFilter<AuthorizationHeaderParameterOperationFilter>();
                    x.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc => apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo)
                        ? methodInfo.Name
                        : new Guid().ToString());
                };
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Swagger Functions Class :-

```
namespace ADPScheduleRequestService
{
    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    public static class SwaggerFunctions
    {
        [SwaggerIgnore]
        [FunctionName("Swagger")]
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "v1/swagger/json")]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            [SwashBuckleClient] ISwashBuckleClient swashBuckleClient)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(swashBuckleClient.CreateSwaggerJsonDocumentResponse(req));
        }

        [SwaggerIgnore]
        [FunctionName("SwaggerUi")]
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run2(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "v1/swagger/ui")]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            [SwashBuckleClient] ISwashBuckleClient swashBuckleClient)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(swashBuckleClient.CreateSwaggerUIResponse(req, "v1/swagger/json"));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you are getting this error because the swagger ui is not being able to access the swagger json 's server url
- if you send a get request to `/swagger/json`you will get something like this

[image]

Swagger is not being able to access this url

- you can change this url by adding the following configuration in the startup.cs class

```
 opts.OverridenPathToSwaggerJson = new Uri("<URL OF SWAGGERJSON >");
```

Also get this url from the portal as auth matters because swagger ui wants to access to the url

[image]